# Observables (angular 2) doesn't return empty data

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying this tutorial http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview
And I want to execute wiki smart component if user input more then 3 chars.
I did this changes

```
  items:Observable<string[]> = this._searchTermStream
    .debounceTime(300)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .switchMap((term:string) => {
        if (term.length > 3) {
          return this._wikipediaService.search(term);
        } else {
          return Observable.empty();
        }
    }
```

but it doesn't work. Still shows old founded data. But I want to show nothing.

Comment: What is not working? Have you debugged it?

Comment: @AdrianKrupa yeah, i tried to debug. It still shows the old founded data

Comment: Not sure I understand what you say. In any case, returning `Observable.empty` is not going to pass an empty object (it in fact does not pass anything down the stream), if that is what you want. You should rather do something like `return Observable.return({})` (supposing {} is your empty object, it could also be null, "", false, undefined, etc. whatever allows you to empty what is displayed on the screen).

Comment: @user3743222 thanks i tried so Observable.of([]); Now list is hidden if user input less then 3 chars.

Answer (score 0):

the definition of the Observable.empty()

Creates an Observable that emits no items to the Observer and immediately emits a complete notification.

it is not means the stream will return a blank array. it just trigger the complete of it self